# How can I convert function type?

Tags: function, go

I want to use upCase as a variable in expend, But it said "Cannot use 'upCase(s1)'(type string) as type func(string) string.
how can I to convert upCase type? Or what do I need do to make the wrong disappear?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "test func"
    s1 := ""
    test := expand(s, upCase(s1))
    fmt.Print(test)
}
func expand(s string, f func(string) string) string {
    s1 := "test"
    var s2 string
    if strings.Contains(s, s1) {
        // todo 字符串中s1的值更改为f(s1)的值
        s1 = f(s1)
        strings.Replace(s1, s, s2, -1)
    } else {
        return ""
    }
    return s2
}

func upCase(s string) string {
    s = strings.ToUpper(s)
    return s
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `upCase` function in your call to `expand` (so it returns a string that you pass to your `expand` function). You need to pass in the function:

```
test := expand(s, upCase)
```

Your current code `test := expand(s, upCase(s1))` is the same as doing:

```
v := upCase(s1)
test := expand(s, v)
```

I.e, you are just calling `upCase(s1)` that returns a string, and you pass that string to `expand` , which expects a function, not a string as its 2. argument.

Comment: yeah! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can You tell me how it works?
And all functions types are their return values? e.g `func a` return int,  when i use `a()` it values is int, but i use `a` it value is `func a`

Comment: @nhas functions in Go are first class. Learn more here: https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+first+class+functions

Comment: Yeah, I know. If i call function as `a` without brackets The name of function is a pointer that point to function. But when i use `a()` the value is a pointer that point to function return values if It can do.
Thanks a lot

Comment: `a()` calls the a function with no arguments. The function `a` is executed and you get back the return value from that call. That return value has a certain type (not neccesarily a pointer). `func a() int { return 1}` returns an int, `val := a()` will make `val` an int. While `func a() *int { var v int = 1 return &v}` `val := a()`   makes `val` a pointer to int.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thanks